# javascript get the mean value of array object with the same key by lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given a array like this

```
const a = [
    {
        mScore: 25,
        cScore: 30,
        fScore: 42,
    },
    {
        mScore: 20,
        cScore: 38,
        fScore: 40,
    },
    {
        mScore: 23,
        cScore: 33,
        fScore: 46,
    }
];
```

What I want is trying to get the average score of different subject, for example, in `m` subject, the average score would be `(25 + 20 + 23) / 3`, as for `c`, it would be `(30 + 38 + 33) /3`

How can I achieve this by `lodash` or `javascript`?

Really appreciate your answer, Thank You.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: Title says "mean" and you are calculating "average"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const a = [
    {
        mScore: 25,
        cScore: 30,
        fScore: 42,
    },
    {
        mScore: 20,
        cScore: 38,
        fScore: 40,
    },
    {
        mScore: 23,
        cScore: 33,
        fScore: 46,
    }
];

const result = {
    m: _.mean(a.map(i => i.mScore)),
    c: _.mean(a.map(i => i.cScore)),
    f: _.mean(a.map(i => i.fScore)),
};
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using pure JavaScript and the `reduce` method

```js
const a = [{
    mScore: 25,
    cScore: 30,
    fScore: 42,
  },
  {
    mScore: 20,
    cScore: 38,
    fScore: 40,
  },
  {
    mScore: 23,
    cScore: 33,
    fScore: 46,
  }
];

let mMean = a.reduce((acc, e) => (acc + e.mScore), 0) / 3;
let cMean = a.reduce((acc, e) => (acc + e.cScore), 0) / 3;
let fMean = a.reduce((acc, e) => (acc + e.fScore), 0) / 3;

console.log(mMean);
console.log(cMean);
console.log(fMean);
```